# Getting the "name" of an item in my.settings

Tags: vb.net

I want the name of if a my.settingings.count, not the value. Example below:

```
Dim bind()() As Object = {
  New Object() {"countForward"},
  New Object() {"countInstalls"},
  New Object() {"countKeys"},
  New Object() {"countUpgrade"}}

For Each ary In bind
  My.Settings(CStr(ary.First)) = "0"
Next
```

What I want is something simular to this:

```
Dim bind()() As Object = {
  New Object() {my.settings.countForward.name},
  New Object() {my.settings.countInstalls.name},
  New Object() {my.settings.countKeys.name},
  New Object() {my.settings.countUpgrade.name}}
```

Thanks Sandy

Comment: The items in settings are not "names" (as in` My.Settings("Keys")`). The Dots mean they are properties and each setting is an Object which the IDE creates them for you. Please read [Ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Reflection

```
' get properties whose names contain "count"
' return as object arrays

Dim bind()() As Object =
    My.Settings.
    GetType().
    GetProperties().
    Where(Function(p) p.Name.Contains("count")).
    Select(Function(p) New Object() {p.Name}).
    ToArray()
```

EDIT

I did some more digging, and you don't need Reflection at all. There is a property called `Properties` which returns only user properties.

```
Dim bind()() As Object =
    My.Settings.Properties.
    OfType(Of Configuration.SettingsProperty).
    Select(Function(p) New Object() {p.Name}).
    ToArray()
```

Comment: Thank You Plutonix. I don't think this does what I want. I write my code so that when I change something, everything tracks the change. For example if I was to change my.settings.countY to my.settings.indexY, I don't think your code works because you are looking for a constant "count". It's cool but not what I was looking for.

Comment: @Sandy I'm not Plutonix but see my new answer.

Comment: Ok, that is some cool code. Sometimes I find it difficult to get across what I am trying to do or want. The code you provided gives me everything in my.settings. I am looking for just the 4 items the 1st example. What I am trying to do I already do with labels, textboxes...because they all have a name attribute. It looks like the code you provided might allow me to look for my.settings.countKey but it is beyond me for now.

Comment: As you noted, this gets all your setting names. If you must logically filter which are returned, look at your settings and see whether there is some pattern to the ones you want. This is what the `Where(Function(p) p.Name.Contains("count"))` was for (before the Select), but you said this pattern doesn't work. Maybe you could elaborate a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

CallByName(My.Settings, nameOfProperty, Microsoft.VisualBasic.CallType.Get, Nothing)